# Installing Sqlite3 on Ubuntu 14.04 for Python3.6

Tags: sqlite, tensorboard

I have a virtual environment set up with python 3.6. I'm trying to install sqlite3 (I built python from source) and am having trouble doing so. (I need sqlite3 for tensorboard)

After some digging I found an approach:

1. sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
2. Now in the downloaded python source rebuild and install python with the following command:
   ./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && sudo make install

The issue is I cannot run the first command. Running the first command gives me the error "download failed Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed." Therefore I downloaded the libsqlite3-dev file.

My question is, where should this be placed before I can run step 2.

I've looked around for a solution for a few hours now ans seem to be at a loss. Any help would be really appreciated with either solving this approach or proposing another approach.

Comment: The best is to use conda to create an env with python3.6 and sqlite3

Comment: I have python3.4 installed as the default. If I install anaconda with python3.6, would this cause any issues I should look out for? thanks

Comment: I have tried and I had no issue.

Comment: Which virtual env. do you use now?

Comment: python virtual env. I create it using the command <absolute path to python3.6 executable directory>/bin/python3.6 -m venv name_of_env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Anaconda

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
conda create -n envsq python=3.7
source activate envsq
python
```

And you can import *sqlite3* with no issues.

Comment: would it be possible to please point me to the miniconda install with python 3.6? i don't think I saw it in the install archive, or may have missed it. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I need python3.6 specifically since it fully supports tensorflow

Comment: ok i think I found it Miniconda3-3.6.0-Linux-x86_64.sh. I would appreciate it if you could please confirm this version is correct for python3.6. thanks

Comment: i ended up following exactly the steps in the official answer and just changed python=3.7 to python=3.6 and everything worked, including all my tensorflow dependencies.